# Getting error in Export progress while selecting schema for export

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to export schema but it's giving me an error in Export progress section

```
Error Fetching Table List From CityState (DbMySQLQuery.resultFieldStringValueByName(): MySQL_ResultSet::isNull: invalid value of 'columnLabel')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like for some MySQL workbench versions: Any upper case letters in any table names or the schema name prevents fetching table names for Data Export

Reference:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103783

Answer (score 0):

create another schema with lowercase letters
then copy table data and export new schema

```
CREATE TABLE new_schema.my_table LIKE old_schema.my_table;
INSERT INTO new_schema.my_table SELECT * FROM old_schema.my_table;
```